# comparing two topologies where their bases are subsets of each other

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

Suppose I have two bases $X$ and $Y$ that generate the topologies $T_X$ and $T_Y$ respectively. If $X$ can be shown as a proper subset of $Y$, does that mean that $T_X$ is strictly coarser than $T_Y$. For example, if I say

$$ X = \{(a,b) \vert a,b \in \mathbb R, a<b \}$$
and
$$ Y = \{[c,d) \vert c,d \in \mathbb R, c<d \}$$

I could always choose $a,b,c,d$ such that $c<a, \text{and} \,d>b$ so that the open interval $(a,b)$ is inside $[c,d)$. Can I use this to argue that $X \subset Y$ and so $T_X \subset T_Y$?

Comment: Beware that a topology is also a basis of itself while any other basis of it is strictly coarser than that special basis.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a proper subset of $Y$, then $T_X$ is coarser than $T_Y$, but you cannot show that it is *strictly* coarser in general. Indeed, you can always add redundant sets to $X$ to produce a strictly bigger $Y$, which generates the same topology.

In the example you gave, it is not true, that $X \subseteq Y$. In fact those sets are disjoint. It is however true, that any set $(a,b) \in X$ is contained in $T_Y$, as $(a,b) = \bigcup_{d \in (a,b)} [d,b) \in T_Y$. Hence $T_X$ is a coarser topology than $T_Y$ (and in fact strictly coarser, as $[0,1) \notin T_X)$.